# Itertools python 2.7 Combinations getting output "Killed" in terminal. Aarch64 linux

Tags: python, python-itertools

I stole Charles Duffy's code on line 9.

here is my code now:

```
from itertools import combinations
def rSubset(arr, r):

    return set(list(combinations(arr, r)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    r = 10
    for item in combinations(arr, r): print(item)
```

When I run this in my terminal (`python passwordgenerator.py`) I get a few seconds of a list and then my terminal freezes :(

Any thoughts?

Also would there be any way to chop this up into little pieces where I could generate a few lines, then write to a txt file, then generate a few more lines, then write to a file?

Edit:
Maybe I could use a loop and a break and a continue? I'm a bit of a python noob right now btw.

Comment: `combinations` is generating a *lot* of combinations, and you are trying to build a concrete list of all of them in memory.

Comment: There are 107 *trillion* possible 10-element combinations of your 62 characters; do you have 12,000 GB of RAM?

Comment: You get no output because your computer runs out of memory before the `set` can be created and passed to `print` as its argument.

Comment: You *could* do something like `for x in combinations(arr, r): print(x)`, which will write each combination to standard output as it is generated, using a small, constant amount of memory, but you will likely fill your disk before the code completes several days from now.

Comment: Linux has a process called the "OOM killer" -- when the system is out of memory, it kills off processes to free some up. Hence, running out of memory can show up as a SIGKILL instead of having an allocation request fail.

Comment: BTW, you can iterate over combinations without needing to realize them in memory, so there's no _good reason_ for your code to run out of memory, if you just wrote it a little differently. `for item in combinations(arr, r): print(item)` won't need to store every item in memory at once.

Comment: Would it be possible to just put all this text directly onto a google doc?